# update table access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a table in which i want to update a multiple rows.
the row data is like this:

```
Cars/Audi/Norway/model1/sports.Jpeg
Cars/Audi/Norway/model1/classic.Jpeg
Cars/Audi/Norway/model1/v8.Jpeg
Cars/Audi/Norway/model1/v6.Jpeg
```

now i want only to update the model1, let say i want to make it model two.
so how can i do it in just one query?
i am using this query:

```
string path="some string";
string name = "some string";

("select replace(filepath,'" + path + "','" + name + "')
```

so it seem like

```
    Cars/Audi/Norway/model10/sports.Jpeg
    Cars/Audi/Norway/model10/classic.Jpeg
    Cars/Audi/Norway/model10/v8.Jpeg
    Cars/Audi/Norway/model10/v6.Jpeg
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE CarImages
SET Path=Replace(Path,'/Model1/','/Model10/');
```

Assuming that the table is called 'CarImages' and the field you want to update is called Path.

Comment: There's some info [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php) about the Replace function in Access

Comment: Replace will only work running inside Access, it is a VBA function, not a Jet/ACE function. It will not work with C#, because that is using Jet/ACE. I am afraid this answer is not correct.

Comment: @duncanmhor this isnt working, because you can read i am using c# and access so this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

replace is only available when working within Access itself, it is a VBA function, not Jet/ACE. You will need something like:

```
SELECT Left([field1],InStr([field1],"/model1")-1) 
    & "/model2" 
    & Mid([field1],InStr([field1],"/model1")+Len("/model1")) AS result
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: You can use it for both, but the exact example Remou posted will only select (note the keyword "SELECT").